# How to subtract a column of date values by sys.Date() using mutate - tidyverse/dplyr? R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe I am working with.

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130),
           date = c("10/7/2021","10/6/2021","9/13/2021","10/18/2021","8/12/2021","9/6/2021","10/29/2021","9/6/2021"))
```

My goal is create a new column that tells me how many days have passed since that recorded date for each row. I'm trying to use this code but I keep getting NA days in my new column.

```
 data %>% 
   select(id,date) %>% 
   mutate("days_since" = as.Date(Sys.Date()) - as.Date(date,format="%Y-%m-%d"))

   id       date days_since
1 123  10/7/2021    NA days
2 124  10/6/2021    NA days
3 125  9/13/2021    NA days
4 126 10/18/2021    NA days
5 127  8/12/2021    NA days
6 128   9/6/2021    NA days
7 129 10/29/2021    NA days
8 130   9/6/2021    NA days
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: The specified format is wrong; it should be `as.Date(date,format="%m/%d/%Y")`. Then your code will work just fine.

Comment: try `Sys.Date() - as.Date(date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')` or `Sys.Date() - lubridate::mdy(date)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `lubridate` package. It makes type conversion and operations with dates much easier.
In your code, the `as.Date(date)` step was problematic because the format was wrong.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>% mutate("days_since" = Sys.Date() - mdy(date))

   id       date days_since
1 123  10/7/2021         28
2 124  10/6/2021         29
3 125  9/13/2021         22
4 126 10/18/2021         17
5 127  8/12/2021         23
6 128   9/6/2021         29
7 129 10/29/2021          6
8 130   9/6/2021         29
```

Thanks, @Karthik S for the simplification

Comment: You need not give `day(Sys.Date() - day(mdy(date))`, just `Sys.Date() - mdy(date)` is enough

Comment: Hum, nice suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

it is also easily done, using base r and a simple "-". This gives back the difference in days:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130),
                   date = c("2021-10-10","2021-10-06","2021-09-13","2021-10-18","2021-08-12","2021-09-06","2021-10-29","2021-09-06"))

data$date <- as.Date(data$date)
data$sys_date <- Sys.Date()

data$sysDate_to_date <- data$sys_date -data$date
```